# When to use <> in kv language

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to ask what is the difference between these three pieces of code (kv language) and why it makes sense to distinguish between them:

1)

```
Location:

<Location@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ...
```

2)

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ...
```

3)

```
<Location@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ...
```

If I understand correctly we use <> to make a rule, class, something reusable for the future. If we don't use <> it's a one-time thing. I might be completely wrong here.. 
Anyway, in the first example, do we add 'Location:' so that it's easely referenced in the future or for other reasons?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking ... in kv language <> denotes a class @ is inheritance

Answer (score 3):

```
<Location@BoxLayout>:
```

This is a dynamic class, without a corresponding python class declaration.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

This is a root widget definition. It will be used automatically as the root widget of your application if the kv file is the one automatically loaded by your application, or it will be returned by `Builder.load_file` or `Builder.load_string` if you load the kv file manually with these methods.

You don't include the main type of rule:

```
<SomeWidget>:
    ...
```

This defines a rule for a widget class that has been declared in python, e.g. `class SomeWidget(Widget)` in one of your python files. The contents of the rule will be applied to every instance of that widget.

This is documented mainly [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file).

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, the link as well. Let me know if I understand my first example correctly: <Location@BoxLayout> defines a dynamic class which is named 'Location' and has the properties of BoxLayout. 'Location:' calls this definition (so to speak) so that it can be displayed on the screen.